# How can I make interesting photographs of interesting things found on the streets?

Tags: composition, street-photography

I was walking through streets of San Francisco and found this interesting advertisement:

[image: giraffe pole banner]

The subject is obviously interesting, but the image here is very straightforward and feels comparatively boring. How can I translate the interest of the subject into an equally-compelling photograph?

Comment: Photography is a hobby for a lot of us — _that_ definitely doesn't invalidate the question. The problem is that the question is kind of vague and open-ended, making it hard to give a correct answer — which means it _may_ not work so well for this site.

Comment: I think this question can be easily saved by saying what you don't like about this and we can help guide you in a direction to change that.  Personally, I think contrast is too low and a different angle in the composition would help.

Comment: It's still a very interesting question, and I'd love to hear what the excellent photographers here have to say. Perhaps if it was made community wiki?

Comment: @rfusca Changed the title but still couldn't find a better one. Please feel free to edit.

Comment: @Craig Walker flagged to make it CW!

Comment: @Shoban - What specifically don't *you* like about it and maybe we can help with that.

Comment: See also [Should Photo Critiques be allowed?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed) and [How can we do photo critiques?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-can-we-do-photo-critiques) on [meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Either the question is too general and it should be closed (which is what it currently is IMO).  OR it gets edited to be more specific about what aspect you don't like and what could be done to change it.   Its awfully general right now.  This really isn't what CW is meant for.

Comment: IMHO this is a good question, as in some way it's not really asking for general critique. it can be seen as asking suggestions to get a good shot of a specific thing (a bit like showing a photo of a person with, say, blue eyes, black hair and a big nose, to get advice on good techniques for a portrait of someone having such characters). it's easy to make this more accurate so everyone will be happy with it, and it is good that many have suggested this.

Comment: I've edited the question a little bit to focus it somewhat. I've put some words in your mouth in doing that, @Shoban, so please fix it back if it's not what you meant, and/or elaborate. Particularly, it would be helpful to know what you _don't_ like about your current image.

Comment: Everyone, Sorry if my question was misleading. I din't know how to phrase it. The subject  looks  very interesting but the end result is not what I was expecting. I am just learning and wanted your ideas so that I don't miss any of my future shots.

Comment: Keep in mind the lamp post photo is just an example - the question seems to be more about basic composition concepts. Isolation and context spring to mind.

Comment: Ah... I just noticed @mattdm edited the title, so the original question was indeed asking about this specific photo and thus the initial comments and answers were referring to it. However, the edited title is a better way of phrasing the question.

Comment: @Leorex: the _original_ original title was not specific: it was "How to take better street art or interesting photographs?". So I went back a slightly-more-specific version of that.

Comment: This has been flagged a couple times. For now, there seem to be some very good answers, and this question has certainly spurred some good discussion. I don't really think it should be CW, and I personally don't want to close it myself, as my vote is immediately binding. I think its up to the community to decide how it wants to handle questions like this. I certainly don't see any problem reworking the question to make it more viable, as there are some very good and useful answers so far.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've identified your subject, the tricky part is expressing what you want to say to others in a single picture. What is it you want to say?

In your example photo, everything is in focus, there is little contrast between the post and background, and everything has vertical lines. How is the viewer meant to know what parts of the photo are important? What is it you want to show people?

The pole decoration incorporated into the banner? http://www.flickr.com/photos/mochiland/205416509/lightbox/

The pole in its environment? http://www.flickr.com/photos/lhirlimann/4375549238/lightbox/

Something a little more 'dynamic'? http://www.flickr.com/photos/cogdog/2773153913/lightbox/

There's a ton of information about 'composition' on the web just waiting to be Googled. Some of it good, a lot of it so-so. Take it all as suggestion, rather than set-in-stone rules - as you develop as a photographer, you'll find your own way to do things.

Study photos you like (your own and other people's) - work out what it is you like about it and how it was done. Shoot as much/often as you can - to improve you need practice, practice, practice.

For starters though, direct people to what they should be looking at.
(The links below are just extrem'ish examples grabbed from a quick Flickr search.)

Try separating your subject from the background (differences in colour, brightness, focus). http://www.flickr.com/photos/southen/5610096056/lightbox/

Draw attention to your subject - contrast between subject and background, lines pointing to the subject. Have a path for the eye to follow to the subject. http://www.flickr.com/photos/mecan/81470204/lightbox/ 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/sparth/5730541580/lightbox/ 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/smash13/5713904476/lightbox/

Is size important? Give a sense of scale by including something that people know the size of (eg a person, car, or building). http://www.flickr.com/photos/gabricabri/5713429646/lightbox/

Is the subject of out place? Show how it is different from others (eg a giraffe pole peeking out of a row of normal light poles, or the giraffe pole 'eating' a tree).

Before raising the camera to your eye, compose the photo in your mind. Know what it is you want to capture, then position yourself and make the photo.

Comment: That last photo is tripping me out.

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer to a open ended question - well done

Answer (score 11):

At least as I see it, the big problem right now is that the background intrudes too much into the picture -- in fact, it *almost* looks like it's intended to be a picture of the building, and this ad just happened to be in the way.

There are a number of possibilities for making the subject stand out more. First, I'd almost certainly cross the street so you're shooting along the street instead of across it. At least in most cases, this means most of the background will be a lot farther away.

Then I'd consider one of two approaches:

1. Get quite close and shoot upward with a much wider-angle lens (if you have one). This will tend to exaggerate the height (probably a good thing in this case) *and* makes objects in the background get a lot smaller in a hurry.
2. The direct opposite of #2: back away a bit farther (still along the same side of the street though) and use a very large aperture (small aperture number) to minimize the depth of field to blur the background as much as possible.

If there's just the one ad like this (in sight) the first is *probably* preferable, especially if you can get nice weather so most of the background is a nice, blue sky (but yes, I realize how uncommon that is in San Francisco...)

If you have a number of the ads in sight, then #2 might be better, assuming you can line things up so you have the one in focus, and more of the same making up a substantial part of the background. If you can get them to nearly fill the frame, it might be worth using more depth of field to get more of them (reasonably) sharp, forming a repeating pattern -- but *only* if you can keep from adding distractions in the process.

It *might* be interesting to try a variation of that last idea even if there's only the one ad in sight, but with other light poles in the background as kind of metaphorical giraffes. It's hard to guess how well that kind of thing will work until you see it though (and sometimes even after you take the picture, it's hard to decide whether it really worked or not). The more metaphorical you get, the more sophisticated the audience needs to be to have a hope of "getting" it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd try to find a more appealing background to the pole. From this perspective, you have a 'boring' building which barely adds to the sense of location. Shooting from the other side of the street (i.e., from the pole's side), you may be able to catch a better, more detailed background. It may be less regular and geometric which can help isolating the subject (or not) and you definitely will have more depth to get a better blurring of the background.

Answer (score 5):

I often wonder the same thing when I see interesting stuff just wondering about. I've found a few things I try to keep in mind when taking those types of shots:

- Background -- what will end up being the backdrop of my subject?
- Framing -- try to frame the shot in an interesting and unique way, your subject doesn't **have** to be in the center
- Perspective -- Try getting some interesting perspective on the subject, in your example. I'd try shooting from below or from above instead of straight on. Get a good angle on the subject that helps make it more interesting

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the answers about perspective. I would try to get way down low and shoot up at the sign. People are so acclimated to looking at things from 5-6 feet above the ground that when they see a picture taken from that range their reaction is many times, meh. Whereas if you show someone something they may have even seen before, but it's from a totally different perspective they will usually be really drawn in.